# Mongodb v3.2 identify the user position after sorting all users points(alternative for rank)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Need your help to find the rank of a user based on his points in a NodeJs server with mongodb v3.2 and as of me the best way to do is to sort all users through their points and find the position of the user after that(much appreciated if anyone let me know other much simpler way to do the same in v3.2)

```
[{'uId': 1,'point':5},{'uId': 2,'point':3},{'uId': 3,'point':12},{'uId': 4,'point':9},{'uId': 5,'point':3}]
```

Above is a sample and the server has 10+ Million records and so looking for an optimized way in Mongo v3.2.

Comment: The answer may vary if this is static or dynamic data (the rate of changes) and according to the number of times this action needs to be performed...if this data is rather static and the action performed man times, I would suggest binning.

Comment: This data gets updated once in a day. operation to find the user ranking is based on the number of users. Also i am binning the top 100 in redis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is to use the Mongo find query with sort and Javascript findIndex.

1. `const data = db.users.find({condition}).sort({"points":-1})` => will return the data that fits the condition and in descending order of points
2. `const rank = data.findIndex(d => d.uId === 2)+1;` => will now provide the rank of my user.